# Firestore rules allow subcollection

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My db structure is like this:

```
//Sub collections
/inventory/{inventoryId}/armor/chest/
/inventory/{inventoryId}/armor/head/
...
// Document
/inventory/{inventoryId}.ownerUID  // ownerUID = firebaseID
/inventory/{inventoryId}.charName // Character  name that owns this inventory, each user can own multiple characters, each character has one inventory linked to it
```

Probably not relevant:

```
 /characters/{charName}.ownerUID
 /characters/{charName}.charName
 /characters/{charName}.inventoryID
```

I'm trying to write the rules so each user can only read/write inventories that belong to him, for the top document in inventory I can just write something like:

```
match /inventory/{inventoryID}/{document=**} {
    allow read,write: if request.auth != null && resource.data.ownerUID == request.auth.uid
}
```

However, this will fail for nested collection as the resource.data.ownerUID only exists at the top level.

Is there a way I can get `{inventoryID}` from `/inventory/{inventoryID}/{document=**}` and check it against firebaseID or maybe somehow use the data from `/character/`

Is my only option adding `ownerUID` to every subcollection of `/inventory`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to [use fields from other documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) than the one that matches the `match` pattern, you can use `get()` to read that document and use its fields.  For example:

```
match /inventory/{inventoryID}/{document=**} {
    allow read, write: if
      get(/databases/$(database)/documents/inventory/$(inventoryID)).data.ownerUID
        == request.auth.uid;
}
```